# Converting ".net regex" to php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following text:

```
﻿<ZZZZ> Av
<asdd> 122
<xcxzc> a
<asas> es&
<wewa> n
<zasd> cu
```

This works in C# but not in PHP:

```
(<ZZZZ>\s(.*?)|<YYYY>\s(.*?))\r
```

The closest I got to make it working in PHP was this:

```
(<ZZZZ> (.*)|<YYYY> (.*))
```

But the match index increments after each "or": [Regex test link](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/aRk)

Comment: What's are you trying to achieve? What's your expected output?

Comment: I guess the reason is `\r`. Use `[\r\n]`. https://regex101.com/r/uH5hS4/1 and http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3cZZZZ%3e%5cs(.*%3f)%7c%3cYYYY%3e%5cs(.*%3f))%5br%5cn%5d&i=%3cZZZZ%3e+Av%0d%0a%3casdd%3e+122%0d%0a%3cxcxzc%3e+a%0d%0a%3casas%3e+es%26%0d%0a%3cwewa%3e+n%0d%0a%3czasd%3e+cu.

Comment: i think you need to add end of the line anchor `(<ZZZZ>\s(.*?)|<YYYY>\s(.*?))$`, https://regex101.com/r/dN9xQ0/1

Comment: Wouldnt hurt telling us your expected output. Its not about fixing your problem itself. Maybe some genius here has a better or shorter solution for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The expected output could be figured by looking closely at the C# regex. **But** it would make the question much more useful if you would include the expected result with explanation in your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the expected output, because of your `|` selector the match number of `$2` will vary, that is why you are not getting the correct value on second match. But if you change your regex to match both variants in one single regex, then you will get expected result:

```
(<[ZY]{4}>\s(.*))
```

I had to remove `\r` at the end of the line (you can use multiline flag for this) and the `?` in `(.*)` block (the * says 0 or many occurrences, so the ? is not necessary).

You can [fiddle around here](https://regex101.com/r/eX3rQ6/1)

You should use the global (g) modifier when you want this to run over all text.

**Explanation**
The `[ZY]` selector will select either Z or Y.
The `{4}` states that you are expecting exactly 4 repetitions of the selector before, so ZZZZ or YYYY.
The `(.*)` needs no ? because the `*` already selects *none* or many.

Comment: `[ZY]{4}` matches four of `Z` or `Y` in any combination (`ZZZY`, `YZYZ`, etc.).  If you want to match only `YYYY` or `ZZZZ`, you need to use another capturing group: `([ZY])\1{3}`